# After review audit failed, answer becomes invisible

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-queues, review-audits

I failed a review audit. I don't know why I failed it, because I can't see it anymore.

So "STOP, Look and listen" doesn't apply here. There is no way for me to analyze what was wrong.

I think it's a bug.

[image: example]

Comment: It means the answer was deleted and only 10k+ users can see deleted posts. This has been brought up before - I'll try and find it...

Comment: Over on Meta.SE:["Allow all reviewers to see deleted posts they reviewed"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed)

Comment: Tangential:  I was looking through your reviews to find the failed audit, and you've flag a lot of questionable stuff as "Looks OK":  http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8754698, http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8754877, http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8754820, http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8754635.  I'm not sure you understand the nuances of reviewing.

Comment: FYI, here's the audit you failed (you approved spam):  http://i.stack.imgur.com/TgsEz.png.  The link at the end should have been a big red warning flag.

Comment: I can't see the question it was related to but how would configuring windows update be on topic on a programming Q&A?

Comment: @NathanOliver - Forgot to link [the relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624934/interfacing-with-windows-drivers); the question is way too broad and borderline off-topic, and without the spam link the "answer" still didn't even answer the question

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables after seeing the question and the answer I will totally agree with spam.  Thank you for linking to the question.  I wasn't able to find it in the review history.  Do you know if audits are not shown in the public profile?

Comment: I see. I didn't notice the link. But I should still be able to see it afterwards, so it's a bug!